# This code just won't print the linked list

Tags: c++

I have been learning about linked lists. I was writing the below code to print a linked list. But it just won't print the list. Can anybody help me troubleshoot?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include "getline.h"
 using namespace std;


 struct Node
 {
  string name, dream;
  Node *randomptr;
 };


 Node *Populating(){


  cout << "Enter name(press enter to exit): ";
  string name = GetLine();   
  if(name == "") return NULL;

  Node *newOne = new Node; 
  cout << "enter dream: "; 
  string dream = GetLine();
  newOne->randomptr = NULL;
  return newOne;

 }

 void PrintNode(Node *eachnode)
  {
  cout << eachnode-> name<<endl;
  cout << eachnode-> dream << endl;

 }

 Node* BuilingLinkedList(){

    Node *listHead = NULL; 
 while(true)
   {
     Node *newOne = Populating();  
     if(newOne == NULL) break;  
     newOne->randomptr=listHead;
     listHead = newOne;
   }
   return listHead;  
 }

 void PrintList(Node *list) 
 {
   for(Node *cur = list;  cur!= NULL; cur = cur->randomptr)    
       PrintNode(cur);  
 } 

 int main()
 {
    Node *list = BuilingLinkedList();
    PrintList(list);
 }
```

Comment: Well, you never populate the nodes for a start... Google "how to debug small programs"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node *Populating(){
 cout << "Enter name(press enter to exit): ";
 string name = GetLine();   
 if(name == "") return NULL;

 Node *newOne = new Node; 
 cout << "enter dream: "; 
 string dream = GetLine();
 newOne->randomptr = NULL;
 return newOne;
}
```

You're not doing anything with `name` or `dream`. They're read into local variables but never assigned to the new node.

Comment: Put them where they need to go. You obviously know how to set the value of `randomptr`, because you've done that already. So, all you have to do is set the remaining members of your new node.

Comment: Thank You..fixed it and now it is working...the thing is that I was actually learning to code linked list and I was just following the steps in the handout...I should have observed more closely.